# Finding the product of user input lines

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3.6.2 - Completely new to programming, and I need to find the product, sum, and average of user input. I have the sum and average down, but I can't seem to get the product to function right. This is what I have so far...

```
#Request input from user
sum = 0
while True:
    try:
        numVar = int(input("Specify number of variables to be entered: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

while True:
    try:
        raw = input("Enter a number or press enter for results: ")
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

while raw != "":
    raw = input("Enter a number or press enter for results: ")
    numbers = int(raw)
    sum += numbers
    ave = round(sum / numVar, 1)
    prd = 1

for count in range(numbers):
    count = count + 1
    prd *= count 

#Print results
print("The sum is" , sum)
print("The average is", ave)
print ("The product is", prd)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: you are really close, you can calculate the product the same way you calculate the sum, try something like `prd *= int(raw)` as the next line after `sum += numbers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got the `sum`, and you can calculate the product the same way you get the sum.

Changing your code as little as possible, but note that we need to change the variable name `sum` to instead something like `total` because `sum` overwrites the built-in python keyword [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Also, I remove the duplicate line where you take user input: `raw = input("Enter a number or press enter for results: ")` which was losing the user input:

```
#Request input from user
total = 0
prd = 1
raw = 0
try:
    numVar = int(input("Specify number of variables to be entered: "))
except ValueError:
    pass

while raw != "":
    raw = input("Enter a number or press enter for results: ")
    try:
        total += int(raw)
        prd *= int(raw)
    except ValueError:
        pass

ave  = round(total / numVar, 1)

print("The sum is" , total)
print("The average is", ave)
print ("The product is", prd)
```

Demo:

```
Specify number of variables to be entered: 4
Enter a number or press enter for results: 3
Enter a number or press enter for results: 4
Enter a number or press enter for results: 5
Enter a number or press enter for results: 6
Enter a number or press enter for results: 
The sum is 18
The average is 4.5
The product is 360
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for your help. I knew it was going to be an easy answer, I just couldn't figure out what I was missing.

Comment: Great I'm glad to hear that, but did you figure out what you were missing? Let me know if it needs more explanation.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I had things in the wrong place, and didn't define others. I knew it was going to be an easy answer, I just couldn't see what it was.